# reg ex match Numeric SubSequence

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a number sequence that I would like to try to match with java regex.

The Test Sequence I am looking to match is 32438993201301501601701

I want to be able to match repeating subsequences 01 that are separated by a single digit and be able to count the number of subsequences in the string.

Comment: Does the final `01` count?

Comment: `preg_match` or `java regex`? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to define a regex that satisfy the given criteria :

> repeating subsequences 01 that are separated by a single digit

you can use this regex :

```
01([0-9]01)+
```

then you can count your subsequences

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches `01` between digits:

```
(?<=\d)01(?=\d)
```

You could split on that and count the size of the returned array minus 1 to find the quantity in the input.

If an `01` at the end of the input counts, allow start/end in the look arounds too:

```
(?<=^|\d)01(?=\d|$)
```

Comment: This will match also `01`'s separated by more than 1 digit.